# Unix - Split to N files using regexp to name destination file

Tags: sed, split

How do I split a file to N files using as a filename the first 2 chars on the line.

Ex input file:

```
AA23409234TEXT
BA23201202Other Text
AA23509234YADA
BA23202202More Text.
C1000000000000000000
```

Should generate 3 files:

AA.txt

```
AA23409234TEXT
AA23509234YADA
```

BA.txt

```
BA23201202Other Text
BA23202202More Text.
```

C1.txt

```
C1000000000000000000
```

I'm thinking of using a sed script similar to this

```
/^(..)/w \1
```

But what that really does is create a file named '\1' instead of the capture group.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk '{fname=substr($0, 0, 2); print >>fname}' input.txt
```

Or

```
$ while read line; do echo "$line" >>"${line:0:2}"; done <input.txt
```

Comment: Thanks that did it. Though I had to increment the third param to substr to 3 as filenames were of only 1 char.

Comment: 4 the awk line: it depends on how many is the 'N'. if it is a huge number, it could generate error like "too many open files". usage of close() could avoid it.  however for small number of files, the awk line works no problem. a good solution though.

Comment: I did ended up with 'Too many open files' error with awk. Of course this was becouse my 'production' problem involved quite more chars than 3.

Comment: @RafaelM you could close the file after you writing text in it. then reopen it if  the prefix matches again. this will be a little slower than keeping it open. but if you do have to write to huge number of files...

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is determine all of your file names:

```
filenames=$(sed 's/\(..\).*/\1/' listOfStrings.txt | sort | uniq)
```

Then, loop through those filenames

```
for filename in $filenames
do
   sed -n '/^$filename/ p' listOfStrings.txt > $filename.txt
done
```

I have not tested this, but I think it should work.

Comment: You can use `filenames=$(grep -o "^.." filename | sort -u)`. However, you're scanning the file multiple times, so performance will be slow.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/\(..\).*/echo "&" >>\1.txt/' file | sh
```

or if you have GNU sed:

```
sed 's/\(..\).*/echo "&" >>\1.txt/e' file
```